# Controller property not exist on ViewContext object in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have my current application which is written in simple ASP.NET MVC application and currently I am migrating it to ASP.NET Core MVC. In my old application I have the following line of code in Razor

```
Culture CurrentRegisteredCulture = (this.ViewContext.Controller as EMPBaseController).CurrentRegisteredCulture;
```

Now in ASP.NET Core, the `Controller` property does not exist on `ViewContext` object. Could you please assist me if there is an alternate way by which I can get the same result as above line of code is doing?

Regards,
Imran

Answer (score 0):

`ViewContext` in ASPNET Core doesn't inherit from `ControllerContext`,but if you want to get `Culture`from `ViewContext`,you can try to use:

```
Culture CurrentRegisteredCulture = this.ViewContext.HttpContext.Features.Get<IRequestCultureFeature>().RequestCulture.Culture;
```